# Eclipse subversion chan't checkout existing project

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

I had a working kepler eclipse on Ubuntu 13.04, x86_64.
Subversion svn, version 1.7.8.
I had several projects in my workspace.
The actual storage was set up on disk as:

```
top:
  ProjA
  ProjB
  ProjC
```

where the different projects where checked out of the subversion repository separately, even though "top" was in the repository, as was top/ProjA, top/ProjB, etc.

I then moved the whole mess to a backup directory and checked out the repository fresh so that each of the project directories were proper subversion subdirectories under top, which is now checked out as a proper subversion directory.

I then copied in the .metadata, .settings, and .project files & directories into the new structure and started eclipse. I get the following message:

```
SVN: '0x00000000: Open Project' operation finished with error: 0x00000000: Unable connect to 'perl' project.
Please check that SVN meta-information exists and its format is supported by the current SVN plug-in version.
If so, it is possible that project working copy is relocated outside plug-in control.
At the current moment project will be automatically disconnected from source control.
0x00000000: Unable connect to 'perl' project.
Please check that SVN meta-information exists and its format is supported by the current SVN plug-in version.
If so, it is possible that project working copy is relocated outside plug-in control.
At the current moment project will be automatically disconnected from source control.
```

Which is expected, because the old directory structure had the svn info in each of the project directories, and now it's located higher up in the tree.

However, when I try to reconnect the project (right-click project, Team->Share Project) to the repository, the Share Project Wizard correctly finds the repository path, selects Simple Mode to connect to the correct URL, but I get the message:
Share Project

> The Project "perl" already exists in repository and has some content.
>   To connect the local project to the specified location, the repository
>   folder content should be checked out. Please consider that applying
>   local changes can cause resource conflicts..."
>   Do you wish to proceed?

I click "Yes", and get:

```
Share project was failed.
svn: E200030: CANTOPEN
```

Any idea on how to proceed?

Configuration:

```
Team SVN Connector: SVNKit 1.7.9
Subversion svn, version 1.7.8.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this kind of problem. In my case, it seems projects are disconnected if there are some latency to access the file (eg network).

After some investigations, the subversive plugin is no more a production tool, and is no more supported....